# TEdit.Text won't update with user entered text

Tags: delphi, vcl

I wrote a program where a `TEdit` (`Edit1`) and `TButton` (`Button1`) are used. When Button1 is pressed, the content of `Edit1.Text` is compared to a string constant. If both are identical, some other buttons will be set active. `Edit1` and `Button1` were directly placed onto `Form1`.

**This all worked.**

Then I rearranged `Form1` (appearance of the window). I added some Panels and GridPanels. `Button1` and `Edit1` moved from `Form1` to `Form1->Panel5->GridPanel2`.

**Since then, things do not work anymore.**

When I read `Form1.Edit1.Text`, only the original text shows up. When the program runs and I type something into `Edit1`, the typed text is visible. But the reading/content
of `Form1.Edit1.Text` does not change.

Is there any setting that stops that the data entered into the edit field is put into `Edit.Text`?

Whatever I type, `Edit1.Text` remains the original content that is in the code (Object Inspector).

I already did it a couple of times that I moved items onto panels and never had such a behavior.

Here is the code, that was not changed after moving `Button1` and `Edit1` onto panels.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //showmessage for debugging to see what the content is
  showmessage(Form1.Edit1.Text);

  if Form1.Edit1.Text = '1234' then
  begin
    // enable a button and an edit
    Form1.Button_Open.Enabled := True;
    Form1.Edit_Id.Enabled := True;
  end
  else
  begin
    showmessage('Wrong input');
   // room for more code
  end;
end;
```

I tried to find settings that stop data entered into the text field from updating `Edit1.Text`, but I did not find anything.

- I deleted `Edit1` and `Button1` and entered new ones with the same names at the places they were before (GridPanel), but that still did not work.
- I deleted `Edit1` and `Button1` and entered new ones with different names at the places they were before (GridPanel), but still did not work.
- I deleted `Edit1` and `Button1` and entered new ones directly on `Form1`, but they also showed the same behavior.

Nothing that I type into the text field finds its way into `Edit1.Text`. It remains the original text that has been typed into the code.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you shouldn't use the global Form1 variable. In fact this is the first thing I delete when creating a new form. With the code you show here you should just delete all references for Form1

Comment: Rearranging controls mainly changes the DFM, so I suspect the error sitting there.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, by looking into the main program/project file:

`Form1` was actually called twice. By deleting the second call, the program started to work as it should.

```pascal
program Project1;

uses
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles,
  EMR.pas {Form1};

{$R *.res}
 
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);  
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1); //called twice!!  
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Keith - Thank you very much. I actually also do not use Form1. In this case I added it deliberately since things were not working as they should... Problem is solved..see my last comment. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Uwe - Thank you very much! Your input made me open the project file (main file) and I found the problem... see my last comment. Thanks again!